# Heading is disappearing and not reacting for CSS changes

Tags: html, css

We have got a problem with our heading. I do not know how we could fix it, because the h2 or a tag is not responsive for changes through CSS.

https://topheizung.ch/heizungspedia/ @400px

The inspector is showing that the a tag is passing the width limit what ends in loosing the word. Do I need to set up a mechanism for break words in our HTML.

[Error Heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwyM0.png)

Comment: Follow this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp and add to your h2 tags

Comment: I see a solution already to break to words. You can always consider to put your font-size of the a element to a relative size such 2vw. It will scale the text based on the view width. https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: Please go read [ask], and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word-break property for **.blog-grid-title-lg** class:

```
.blog-grid-title-lg {
    word-break: break-word; 
}
```

You can also do something like this:

```
.blog-grid-title-lg {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Under you h2 tag there's `<a>` the font-size of the anchor tag is being set to 
`24px !important`

```
.post-type-archive-encyclopedia h2>a {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

remove the important property if you want to scale, and use em